# GridView Selected Index Changed on different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem when I try to get value for a `selectedIndexChanged` that is on another page
within the `GridView`.

```
protected void dgvViewGatesLive_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dgvViewGatesLive.SelectedRow;
    if (row.Cells.Count >= 0)
    {
        Device = row.Cells[1].Text;
        Session["actualDevice"] = Device;
        //some code
        //
    }
}
```

the "Device" bring me the correct row but the data of the first page even if `selectedIndexChanged` is fired from another page of `GridView` for example:

if i select the first row from page 2 the code above brings me the device in the first row from page 1. Here`Device = row.Cells[1].Text;`

**EDIT 1:**

I found the solution as pageload reloaded data in gridView. Needed to reload the current page and update control before using  like this:

```
int page = (int)Session["Page"];
 dgvViewGatesLive.PageIndex = page;
 dgvViewGatesLive.DataBind();
 GridViewRow row = dgvViewGatesLive.SelectedRow;
```

Comment: Please put your solution in your answer instead of an edit.  Also you might consider conditionally binding your gridview in the `page.load`.  If you don't need a new page, you don't need to re-bind on every postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as pageload reloaded data in gridView. Needed to reload the current page and update control before using like this:

```
int page = (int)Session["Page"];
 dgvViewGatesLive.PageIndex = page;
 dgvViewGatesLive.DataBind();
 GridViewRow row = dgvViewGatesLive.SelectedRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two GridViews?

I see you captured the index changed event on `dgvViewGates`.

But you are getting info from `dgvViewGatesLive`.

Comment: No sorry about that, its the same GridView his id is dgvViewGatesLive but onselectedindexchanged="dgvViewGates_SelectedIndexChanged" my bad :S that generates confucion. I fix it now Thx!

Comment: Then something else is happening that is not in the code you posted.

Comment: U ar right about the problem was reloading the control once jumped the click event. Thx!!! :)